# visual basic visualization

Tags: vb.net, graphics, ide, workflow, representation

I am actually looking to find a IDE, a tool or a plugin (for Visual Studio) to have the possibility to create and customize associations of codes-pictures: so that from a "drawing" or concatenation of figures a functional code can be generated (i.e.: from a visual workflow with arrows, boxes, cones etc to a VB code), and from the latter (from the code) have a visual representation (i.e.: from a VB code to a graphical representation of the workflow). 
If you can help. Thanks

Comment: How would you tell the button or 'drawing' what it is supposed to do without code?

Comment: I did not say I do not want to use code.... I have just said that I want to attach some specific code to some specific image, so that at the end I can use either code or image to create my application.

Answer (score 0):

This is too complex for code creation.

But you can visualize existing code if you use Visual Studio Professional/Ultimate

- View Class Diagram (When right-clicking in solution explorer)
- Show On Code Map (When right-clicking on actual code)

Try them, test them with a small project. You will notice that it is not so easy to keep an overview, while it only shows a subset of the complete code.

With Class Diagram you can visually add classes / fields / properties / methods, however, need to use the real code view to fill them.

Comment: Right, maybe I wasn't clear in my explaination.... :)
With Class Diagram I have a visual representation of the code. That is fine, but not what I am looking for here.

In other words: what I have tried to explain here is that I would like to, as an example, use a triangle, and assotiate this triangle to the code Dim myString : set myString "This is a Triangle" so that every time I draw this triangle the code is writen.

Comment: hmm there are some code collection parts. if those parts would never need to be changed themselves, then true, you could program by just using a few blocks

Comment: Exactly!
I am very fresh to vb... any suggestion on how to do it or where to look?

Comment: What your asking is not realistic.  There are some app creators for phone development that don't require code but being 'fresh to VB' and wanting to write an app without writing code inherently means you don't want to use VB, since VB is code.

Comment: I only know those Lego robots/mindstorms as an example for that way of programming. I think one day it could go in that direction, that we just put some blocks together, and they just fit with each other, but I think there are always areas that require a closer look, but who knows, maybe in a few years a few nice ideas may change a lot, we never know. But I doubt, I think if you train 'traditional' programming, then you will be a half-geek and perfect prepared for the visual programming, or for implementing it